# Empathy wont connect to my gmail account

Tags: empathy

Hello I'd like to use empathy for google chat; but even though I added my account to the application without problems (it is shown in the configure pannel)[image]

when I try to log, the cog wheels but it ends up with an error - authentication of your account failed (is your password correct?)

Any hints on what I did wrong ?

Not much success on google and I don't know how to get bug trace either.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have the mail servers correct, then try to enter the password in the browser based gmail. If the password doesn't work there, then you have been putting the wrong password into Empathy.

Comment: Hi @Joshua; I've done that but still no success. I copy'd the password; disconnected from gmail and connected again pasting the password. Then i added new account to instant messaging pasting the password. No success still